# Rock, Paper, Scissors and a Restart Option

Tags: python

I am just beginning to use python and could use some help! I was working on a rock, paper, scissors game and I wanted to add a restart option once either the human or computer reaches 3 wins.

I have looked all over for some answers but from all the other code I looked at seemed way out of my league or extremely different from what I wrote. I haven't tried using def and classes, which I saw a lot of, and made it look very simple. I know I'm probably going about this in a really round about way but I just want to finish this without completely copying someone's code.

```
    import random

    moves = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
    player_score = 0
    computer_score = 0
    draws = 0

    keep_playing = True
    while keep_playing == True:
        cmove = random.choice(moves)
        pmove = input("What is your move: Rock, Paper, or Scissors?")
        print("The computer chose", cmove)
#Logic to game    
        if cmove == pmove:
            print("It's a DRAW!")

        elif pmove == "Rock" and cmove == "Scissors":
            print("--Player Wins!--")

        elif pmove == "Rock" and cmove == "Paper":
            print("--Computer Wins!--")

        elif cmove == "Paper" and cmove == "Rock":
            print("--Player Wins!--")

        elif pmove == "Paper" and cmove == "Scissors":
            print("--Computer Wins!--")

        elif pmove == "Scissors" and cmove == "Paper":
            print("--Player Wins!--")

        elif pmove == "Scissors" and cmove == "Rock":
            print("--Computer Wins!--")

#Scoreboard
        if pmove == cmove:
            draws = draws + 1
            print("Player:" + str(player_score) + ' | ' + "Computer:" + str(computer_score) + ' | ' + "Draws:" + str(draws))

        if pmove == "Rock" and cmove == "Scissors":
            player_score = player_score + 1
            print("Player:" + str(player_score) + ' | ' + "Computer:" + str(computer_score) + ' | ' + "Draws:" + str(draws))

        if pmove == "Rock" and cmove == "Paper":
            computer_score = computer_score + 1
            print("Player:" + str(player_score) + ' | ' + "Computer:" + str(computer_score) + ' | ' + "Draws:" + str(draws))

        if pmove == "Paper" and cmove == "Rock":
            player_score = player_score + 1
            print("Player:" + str(player_score) + ' | ' + "Computer:" + str(computer_score) + ' | ' + "Draws:" + str(draws))

        if pmove == "Paper" and cmove == "Scissors":
            computer_score = computer_score + 1
            print("Player:" + str(player_score) + ' | ' + "Computer:" + str(computer_score) + ' | ' + "Draws:" + str(draws))

        if pmove == "Scissors" and cmove == "Paper":
            player_score = player_score + 1
            print("Player:" + str(player_score) + ' | ' + "Computer:" + str(computer_score) + ' | ' + "Draws:" + str(draws))

        if pmove == "Scissors" and cmove == "Rock":
            computer_score = computer_score + 1
            print("Player:" + str(player_score) + ' | ' + "Computer:" + str(computer_score) + ' | ' + "Draws:" + str(draws))
#Win/lose restart point?
        if player_score == 3:
            print("-----You Win!-----")
            break

        if computer_score == 3:
            print("-----You Lose!-----")
            break
```

I want the code to end saying, "You Win!" or "You Lose!"and then ask for an input to whether or not they want to restart and then it resets the scores and keeps going or if they say no it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the loop to do this. So when you want to "restart" your game, you really just need to reset the scores.

Starting from your win/lose conditions:

```
#Win/lose restart point?
if player_score == 3:
    print("-----You Win!-----")
    replay = input("Would you like to play again?")
    if replay.upper().startswith('Y'):
        player_score = 0
        computer_score = 0
        draws = 0
    else:
        keep_playing = False


if computer_score == 3:
    print("-----You Lose!-----")
    if replay.upper().startswith('Y'):
        player_score = 0
        computer_score = 0
        draws = 0
    else:
        keep_playing = False
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was trying to do! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get user input in the `while` loop and set `keep_playing` accordingly.

```
while keep_playing == True:
    cmove = random.choice(moves)
    pmove = input("What is your move: Rock, Paper, or Scissors?")
    print("The computer chose", cmove)
    #Logic to game    
    if cmove == pmove:
        print("It's a DRAW!")

    elif pmove == "Rock" and cmove == "Scissors":
        print("--Player Wins!--")

    elif pmove == "Rock" and cmove == "Paper":
        print("--Computer Wins!--")

    elif cmove == "Paper" and cmove == "Rock":
        print("--Player Wins!--")

    elif pmove == "Paper" and cmove == "Scissors":
        print("--Computer Wins!--")

    elif pmove == "Scissors" and cmove == "Paper":
        print("--Player Wins!--")

    elif pmove == "Scissors" and cmove == "Rock":
        print("--Computer Wins!--")

    # new code
    play_again = input("Would you like to play again?")
    keep_playing = play_again.lower().startswith('y')  # this will be set to False if the user's input doesn't start with 'y', the loop will exit
```